# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{7}{n(2n-1)}-\frac{3}{7^{n+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find limit of this series:
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{7}{n(2n-1)}-\frac{3}{7^{n+1}}$$

So far I got to

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{7}{n(2n-1)}- \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{7^{n+1}}$$
where
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3}{7^{n+1}} = \frac{7}{12}$$

Comment: I think you should check your work. For the other piece, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18277/computing-the-sum-sum-frac1n-2n-1

Comment: Have you checked your $\sum_1^{\infty}(3/7^{n+1})=7/12$? Have you had a look at the link?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\dfrac2{2n(2n-1)}=\dfrac1{2n-1}-\dfrac1{2n}=-\dfrac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}-\dfrac{x^{2n}}{2n}$$ where $x=-1$

Now for $-1\le x<1,$  $$\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}r$$

See [What is the correct radius of convergence for $\ln(1+x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356517/what-is-the-correct-radius-of-convergence-for-ln1x)